# Problem with Drake Binary Installation for Python

Tags: drake

I used  Drake Binary Installation for Python from this site
https://drake.mit.edu/python_bindings.html#installation

Then when i checked to ensure I can import pydrake, I have got this:

```
dmitriy@dmitriy-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK:/opt$ python3 -c 'import pydrake.all; print(pydrake.__file__)'
/opt/drake/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/__init__.py
```

But when I try execute this example:

```
import pydrake.all

builder = pydrake.systems.framework.DiagramBuilder()
plant, _ = pydrake.multibody.plant.AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, 0.0)
pydrake.multibody.parsing.Parser(plant).AddModelFromFile(
  pydrake.common.FindResourceOrThrow(
      "drake/examples/pendulum/Pendulum.urdf"))
plant.Finalize()
diagram = builder.Build()
simulator = pydrake.systems.analysis.Simulator(diagram)
```

I get this:

```
No module named 'pydrake'
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you cite shows how to `export PYTHONPATH` (or alternatively, how to us a virtualenv).  Since the first command you posted works, you must have done those steps correctly.  Thus, the second command should have also worked.

Maybe you ran the second command in a new terminal, without the correct environment set up?

Comment: Thanks, It worked in the same terminal as you said. But now new quations have appered:
1. Can I somehow use this pydrake without  writing this command at every new terminal session ?
python3 -c 'import pydrake.all; print(pydrake.__file__)'
2. As I like to use Visual Studio Code, can I carefully use pydrake with jupyter notebook in VSC ?

Comment: The important command isn't the "print", it's the above `export PYTHONPATH=...` line.  As long as you do "export" in the terminal you're using to launch jyputer, you should be fine.  It's a standard convention of Python, not anything Drake specific.

Comment: Thank you, but does some ability exist for don't writing `export PY...` at every new terminal session ?